# Serialize Java object - get only required attributes - Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have two bean classes **Teams** and **Players**

Teams bean has few properties like Id, Name, Description, Location and list of Players.
Players bean has few properties like Id, Name, Age etc.

I have a service which returns the list of teams(JSON) and I want the output to return all the properties in Teams and only two properties in Players(Id and Name).

How can I serialize the TeamsList object in such a way that I have only two properties(Id, Name) in the resultant JSON

Currently using @AutoWired - which is returning all the properties of the Player object

**Edit:** There is a service which gives Individual Player details. I need the service to return the other data for that.

Comment: making the fields transient doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Use @JsonIgnore on the Player attributes you don't need.

Comment: There is a service which gives Individual Player details. I need the service to return the other data for that.

Comment: @JsonIgnore will only affect the JSON serialization

Comment: This does not give the exact answer expected, as the author mentioned in the comment, when he does the JsonIgnore then it will ignore the properties of the `Player` class in all the places it gets serialized to JSON, there will be no use in the contract all players method if `Player` class is configured only to return players id and name.